# Utilisation invalide de la clause GROUP

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am getting the error trying to sum scores in a row (record) in my MySql database table. What I am trying to achieve is update the `Total_Score` column in the `term1` table. If there's a change in a any scores then I have to update `Total_Score` column accordingly. Below is part of the coding that gives the error.

```
String qry2 = null;
Prepared statement ps2 = null;

qry2 = " UPDATE term1 SET Total_Score = sum(English + Social_Science + Science  + Maths + PE + MAL Arts) WHERE SID = ?";

ps2.=conn.prepareStatement(qry2);
Int res2=ps2.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Is that your _exact_ code?

Comment: or you could have a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) and not need the `update` statement.

Comment: Fix your broken schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet. In a normalised environment, you would not have separate tables for separate terms, nor separate columns for separate subjects. You might instead have a column for student, a column for term, a column for subject, and a column for mark.

Answer (score 1):

So very many errors in that code:

```
String qry2 = null;
Prepared statement ps2 = null; // Data type is `PreparedStatement`, not `Prepared statement`

// Don't call `sum()` unless you're summing multiple rows, and you're not.
// What is `MAL Arts`? Column names cannot have spaces, unless you quote
//   the name, and you really don't want to be doing that.
qry2 = " UPDATE term1 SET Total_Score = sum(English + Social_Science + Science  + Maths + PE + MAL Arts) WHERE SID = ?";

ps2.=conn.prepareStatement(qry2); // no period before =
Int res2=ps2.executeUpdate(); // Data type is `int`, not `Int`
```

Seems like your code should be:

```
String qry2 = "UPDATE term1" +
             " SET Total_Score = English + Social_Science + Science + Maths + PE + MALArts" +
             " WHERE SID = ?";
int res2;
try (PreparedStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(qry2)) {
    ps2.setInt(1, sid);
    res2 = ps2.executeUpdate();
}
// code using `res2` here
```

Comment: This rather ignores the elephant in the room.!